# Ride request returns 404 page not found in sandbox and prod

Tags: uber-api

I am trying out uber ride request apis. Able to get products , fare estimate both in sandbox and prod. However ride request is returing 404 page not found.
After getting the fare estimate , i immediately make ride request to ensure fare estimate is not expired. I am testing this in postman and postman code is given

Tried in both sandbox and prod and returns same result.
Tried adding product_id in ride request and keeping it optional as well

Fare estimage code

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/estimate \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer token-xyzzabcd' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: api.uber.com' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'content-length: 226' \
  -H 'cookie: marketing_vistor_id=59526eba-b6e3-4024-a8a9-0b9f1c88eb7b' \
  -b marketing_vistor_id=59526eba-b6e3-4024-a8a9-0b9f1c88eb7b \
  -d '{
       "start_latitude": 18.660952,
       "start_longitude": 73.828433,
       "end_latitude": 18.562113,
       "end_longitude": 73.8042427,
       "product_id": "3d67403a-afdc-41a1-9ea9-df68a3f4a835"

     }'
```

Get below response to fare estimate

```
{
    "fare": {
        "breakdown": [
            {
                "type": "base_fare",
                "name": "Base Fare",
                "value": 200.99
            }
        ],
        "value": 200.99,
        "fare_id": "df4b3a6da7cecd7d93bfd08aef2f096cb18b2374c87a97dd639ae54fe4088045",
        "expires_at": 1561107159,
        "display": "₹200.99",
        "currency_code": "INR"
    },
    "trip": {
        "distance_unit": "mile",
        "duration_estimate": 1800,
        "distance_estimate": 10.59
    },
    "pickup_estimate": 6
}
```

Ride request

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/ \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer tokenabcdxyz' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: api.uber.com' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'content-length: 306' \
  -H 'cookie: marketing_vistor_id=59526eba-b6e3-4024-a8a9-0b9f1c88eb7b' \
  -b marketing_vistor_id=59526eba-b6e3-4024-a8a9-0b9f1c88eb7b \
  -d '{
       "start_latitude": 18.660952,
       "start_longitude": 73.828433,
       "end_latitude": 18.562113,
       "end_longitude": 73.8042427,
        "product_id": "3d67403a-afdc-41a1-9ea9-df68a3f4a835",
        "fair_id": "df4b3a6da7cecd7d93bfd08aef2f096cb18b2374c87a97dd639ae54fe4088045"
     }'
```

get below response

```
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. It was becuase of / at the end of hostname  https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/ 
After removing it , the api worked